# Computing mean, median and mode in python

Tags: python, pandas, mean, median, mode

How to calculate central tendency (Median and mode) on pandas columns with Python 3, if the data has given with attribute `Jumlah_individu`?

[image: this is my code to calculate mean (I have get it) but for median and mode I can't]

Comment: Please post code always as text. Code from images cannot be copy-pasted and it also doesn't get indexed by google, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.median()` to get the middle value in a list.

ex. `df['Jumlah_individu'].median()`

You can use `.mode()` to get the highest frequency value in a list.

ex. `df['Jumlah_individu'].mode()[0]` where `[0]`to get the highest frequency value.

Answer (score 4):

Simply try `data.describe()` and you can get that list as shown in the pic

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary for the mean, median and mode

```
CentralTendacy = {}
CentralTendacy['Mean'] = df['Jumlah_individu'].mean()
CentralTendacy['Median'] = df['Jumlah_individu'].median()
CentralTendacy['Mode'] = df['Jumlah_individu'].mode()[0]

CentralTendacy
```